# PHPMailer html not showing images

Tags: php, html, image, phpmailer

I'm using `PHPMailer` to send the registration confirm email to my users with a  full html file. The email shows perfectly except for the pictures are not loaded.

Here I attach my php code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->setFrom($this->Settings->SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = dblang('registration_confirm_email_subject');
if (file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/email/registration/confirm.txt.' . $this->lang->lang() . '.php')) {
    $mail->AltBody = $this->load->view('_email/registration/confirm.txt.' . $this->lang->lang() . '.php',
        $emailData, true);
}

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $this->load->view('_email/registration/confirm.html.' . $this->lang->lang() . '.php',
    $emailData, true);


if($mail->send()) {
    swal_success('registration_email_send_title', 'registration_email_send_text');
    redirect(site_url('home'));
}
```

Here I put a part of the html code. I've tried with relative and absolute urlfor the pictures path:

```
<img src="../../../../../../bets/assets/email/welovesports.png" alt="We Love Sports" border="0" width="290" height="92"
    style="display: block;border: none;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">
```

Comment: You *must* use absolute paths in an email, including the protocol (http://, https://) and the domain name. Otherwise, how would an email client know where to look for the images?

Comment: I've tried with absolute url as well with the protocol

Comment: Well, if `<img src="http://your-domain.test/bets/assets/email/welovesports.png">` doesn't show up in the email client, it is either blocked by the email client or it doesn't exist on the server. Not many other options, really.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, I didn't realize that the domain I was using is a dev server with password so the browser could't get the image. Noob mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tried absolute urls with no luck.
looking on your code reference `../../../../../../bets/assets/email/`
I suggest copy that image to very root of **public_html** -> `/public_html/welovesports.png`
and then reference it as `<img src="http://your-domain.test/welovesports.png">`
because the no. of directories your code suggests, can make it difficult to reference the correct path

---

OR Alternatively

---

you can use http://imgur.com/upload and host your image with them.
and on the gallery page of that image copy its direct link to use it
(it will be like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN1K4.png`)
eg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN1K4.png

Comment: Yes, absolute URL are now wokring. The preoblem is taht I was using the url from a developer server with password. I will upload them on my pubblic server. By now I will use the imgur option. Thank you very much